# Why does my while loop condition not end the loop?

Tags: javascript

I am confused as to why my function continues to loop. wedgesNeeded = number, limes = array

```js
function limesToCut(wedgesNeeded, limes) {
  let total = 0
  while (wedgesNeeded > 0) {
    let lime = limes.shift()
    switch (lime) {
      case 'small':
        wedgesNeeded -= 6;
        total++;
        break;
      case 'medium':
        wedgesNeeded -= 8;
        total++;
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
  return total
}
console.log(limesToCut(12, ['small','small']));
```

Comment: Please include a [mre], with enough code that we can reproduce the situation.

Comment: Are you sure that `lime` has any of the values in the switch? If you put an alert in the `default` case, does that appear?

Comment: Note that if `limes` contains none of those strings, it will loop indefinitely. Also, if `limes` does not contain enough of those string to get `wedgesNeeded` down to 0, it will continue to loop.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I thought the same at first, but if it's default doesn't it move to the next `lime`? `let lime = limes.shift()`; it only gets evaluated once, right? I have no idea why this would loop infinitely; I'd think you'd eventually run out of limes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yeah the values are correct. If I console.log(`${wedgesNeeded} ${total}`) after the switch it will return all the correct values. The total increases correctly and the wedgesNeeded will decrease correctly.

Comment: Ahh I see, if you take more limes than there are entries in the limes array, then you get `undefined`, which DOES trip the default case, then the next attempt also gets `undefined`, etc. Should be a check in there to see if there are any limes remaining before getting a lime.

Comment: Works with the data I added to a Stack Snippet (in an effort to create a [mre]). Please enter the data you are using that produces an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation occurs when the `wedgesNeeded` is much bigger than what you expect; Your loop will empty the `limes` array but `wedgesNeeded` is still bigger than 0

```js
function limesToCut(wedgesNeeded, limes) {
  let total = 0
  while (wedgesNeeded > 0 && !!limes.length) {
    let lime = limes.shift()
        switch (lime) {
          case 'small':
            wedgesNeeded -= 6;
            total++;
            break;
          case 'medium':  
            wedgesNeeded -= 8;
            total++;
            break;
          default:
        }
    }
  return total
}

count = limesToCut(200000, ['small', 'medium', 'small', 'medium', 'small', 'medium'])
console.log(count)
```

**Edit: Replaced the if condition by while condition!**

Comment: This works, thank you. Is there a way to remove the if statement and include another condition in the whileloop instead?

Comment: @Conrade sure, done!

Comment: Legend, mate. What does the '!!' mean?

Comment: [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript?rq=1) @Conrade